# How to get Elantech trackpad to be identified properly, curently has no extended functionality

Tags: hardware, mouse, input-devices, samsung, trackpad

I have a **Samsung RF510** laptop computer. Upon installing Ubuntu 10.10 onto it I could not get the trackpad to function properly. It works as a basic mouse (point and click) but had no functionality for edge scrolling or any of the multitouch settings the trackpad is capable of.

I discovered the reason is a known issue where the Ubuntu kernel will improperly detect an Elantech trackpad as a logitech PS/2 wheel mouse, and as such will gain none of the functionality that seems to be coded for synaptics trackpads.

Is there any way to get this working properly? I would like basic scrolling/zooming/etc I've been used to using these features for as long as I can remember.

Comment: I had a similar problem on my asus. This worked for me: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/681904/comments/64 (afterwards, "sudo rmmod psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse") Note that I don't actually understand what this does and I don't know how to reverse it, so tread carefully.

Answer (score 1):

The method found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1812252) works for me:

```bash
sudo apt-get install dkms
cd /usr/src/
sudo wget http://planet76.com/drivers/elantech/psmouse-elantech-v6.tar.bz2
sudo tar jxvf psmouse-elantech-v6.tar.bz2
sudo dkms add -m psmouse -v elantech-v6
sudo dkms build -m psmouse -v elantech-v6
sudo dkms install -m psmouse -v elantech-v6
```

Comment: This doesn't compile by default, but after adding the extra option that is now required to a line in elantech.c, it still doesn't work...xinput still indicates the touchpad registering as a mouse.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to upgrade to Ubuntu 11.10, that already has built-in support for your touchpad in the kernel.

Comment: Not working out of the box in 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't fix the problem you're having, it does fix all the other problems that exist with the RF510. Things such as the backlight and function keys. He did address the touchpad problem, but doesn't know of a fix at the moment.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1680872